# Do I need to create all the surfaces before creating the device?

Tags: vulkan

just a quick question here...

So, as you know, when you create a Vulkan device, you need to make sure the physical device you chose supports presenting to a surface with `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR()` right?, that means, you need to create the surface before creating the device.

Now lets say that at run-time, the user may press a button which makes a new window open, and stuff is going to be drawn to that window, so you need a new surface right?, but the device has already been created...

Does this mean I have to create all the surfaces before I create the device or do I have to recreate the device, but, if need to recreate it, what happens with all the stuff that has been created/allocated from that device?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean I have to create all the surfaces before I create the device or do I have to recreate the device

Neither.

If the physical device cannot draw to the surface... then you need to find a physical device which *can*. This could happen if you have 2 GPUs, and each one is plugged into a different monitor. Each GPU can only draw to surfaces that are on *their* monitor (though sometimes there are ways for implementations to get around this).

So if the physical device for the logial `VkDevice` you're using cannot draw to the surface, you don't "**re**create" the device. You create a *new* device, one which is almost certainly unable to draw to the surface that the old device could draw to. So in this case, you'd need 2 *separate* devices to render to the two surfaces.

But for most multi-monitor cases this isn't an issue. If you have a single GPU with multi-monitor output support, then any windows you create will almost certainly be compatible with that GPU. Integrated GPU + discrete GPU cases also tend to support the same surfaces.

The Vulkan API simply requires that you check to see if there is an incompatibility, and then deal with it however you can. Which could involve moving the window to the proper monitor or other OS-specific things.